# Return JSONP via AWS Lambda/API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to return jsonp as in callbackname(data.strified)

```
callback( null, 
    ( !!event.cb && event.cb.length > 0 ) 
    ? event.cb.replace( /[^a-z0-9_]/i, '' ) + '(' + JSON.stringify( data ) + ')'
    : data
);
```

My quick and dirty way now returns the data and if ?cb=test is given it returns:

```
"test({\"valid\":false,\"data\":false})"
```

Is there anyway to get rid of the quotes and escape characters?
The API should work with and without callback set.

Comment: I've the same question... Do you have any update? Thanks @Tobias!

Comment: see answer, I think that's the easiest way.

Comment: @IgnacioOcampo you got a solution for it? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you have this type of lambda function:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var data={"test":"data"};
    context.done( null, 
            ( !!event.cb && event.cb.length > 0 ) 
            ? event.cb.replace( /[^a-z0-9_]/i, '' ) + '(' + JSON.stringify( data ) + ')'
            : data
    );
};
```

When you give it an event like

```
{
  "cb": "callback"
}
```

It will give this output:

```
"callback({\"test\":\"data\"})"
```

So far, so good. Now you come to API Gateway and in Integration Response part you write this

```
$util.parseJson($input.json('$'))
```

Than you will get `callback({"test":"data"})` as output when you invoke the API Gateway endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integration mapping template to do this. Something like this should help you to parse the Json.

```
$util.parseJson($input.json('$'))
```

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference) are more details about mapping templates.

Comment: how would I set up the integration mapping template? I kinda already did the above but it now outputs nothing... also would that support json and jsonp? as in pure data vs data wrapped in function name

Answer (score 1):

As Çağatay Gürtürk pointed out, you stringify your result and return it.

However, if your lambda also accepts non callbacks, you can check in the VTL template:

API Gateway and in Integration Response part:

```
#if($input.params('callback') != "")
$util.parseJson($input.json('$'))
#else
$input.json('$')
#end
```