# parse error callback function not called jquery ajax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, get

I have been trying all the methods that i have seen in the stack overflow asked by other users before.But none of them are working.Please hoping any of you would point me in the right direction

```
$.ajax({
 type: "get",
 dataType:'jsonp',
 params:jsonData,
 jsonp:false,
 jsonpCallback:"callbackfn",
 headers: { "api_key": "u5FocU4xLq2rBfZ1ZSV8o81R2usYzUEM3NaCinnV"},
  url: "http://localhost/url?name=xxx&email=xxxxxx@gmail.com",
 success:function(){
  alert("sucess function");
   },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert(textStatus + " and<br> " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
 function callbackfn(data) {
   alert(data);
  }
```

the response is `{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }`

Although the response is json,this rises an error

> Parse error .callbackfn not called.

Comment: @devlincarnate yes.not working

Comment: Javascript implements [hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), so moving the function deceleration wouldn't change anything @devlincarnate

Comment: @citysurrounded yes.exactly.and do you know why this error is arising?

Comment: Perhaps because the response from the service is not valid JSON (hence the parse error)

Comment: Something else at play here that is not posted perhaps?

Comment: @RobM. but the response is json `{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss what might be the other reasons that might rise this error?

Comment: @kevin I'm doing a bit of research, there's a couple of possibilities. Do you know if your server supports JSONP for sure?

Comment: I dont know exactly,But the server i requesting is amazon aws

Comment: @kevin ec2? s3? a specific API? can you be more specific?

Comment: I have created lamda function that send me the names of the pages that the user is administrator of when i make a get request to that api

Comment: @kevin take a look at this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436728/return-jsonp-via-aws-lambda-api-gateway describing how to accommodate jsonp callbacks in a lambda function on AWS. Is this at all helpful? I don't think your server is set up properly to handle jsonp.

Comment: @citysurrounded thankyou very much.I was searching for that only

Comment: @kevin fantastic! if you run into any more trouble, try the solution I outlined in my answer below. Please mark as solution as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a custom callback function with JSONP, you must declare its scope to be global, i.e.

```js
window.callbackfn = function(data) {
    alert(data);
};
```

---

#### Why?

This is because successful JSONP responses return a new JavaScript file, that is, a JavaScript function call encapsulated in `<script>` tags. Since each script is independently evaluated in the global scope, any script's function you would like to be made available to another script must also be declared in the global scope. Thus all JSONP callback functions should be global.

---

#### EDIT

According to OP, the solution found here: [Return JSONP via AWS Lambda/API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436728/return-jsonp-via-aws-lambda-api-gateway) did the trick. Issue had to do with an improper server-side JSONP response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your response from the server is a function call with the response data as the argument. It appears you are just outputting JSON, but JSONP expects a function call with the response data. Your server response should look like this:

```
callbackfn({
  "firstName":"John",
  "lastName":"Doe"
});
```

You have `jsonp: false` with a `jsonpCallback` and `dataType: 'jsonp'` - which is odd, because you are also supplying a jsonp callback. Perhaps if you don't need JSONP due to cross-origin requests, you should remove the `jsonpCallback` argument and just manually call that function with the response:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   dataType:'json',
   params:jsonData,
   headers: { "api_key": "u5FocU4xLq2rBfZ1ZSV8o81R2usYzUEM3NaCinnV"},
   url: "http://localhost/url?name=xxx&email=xxxxxx@gmail.com",
   success:function(data){
     callbackfn(data);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert(textStatus + " and<br> " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: M how can i check that?

Comment: I don't follow, you posted that the response is a plain JS object `{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" }`, but JSONP responses must be the object wrapped in a function call to the supplied function name (`jsonpCallback=callbackfn`) - therefore the server response must be what I posted in my answer.

Comment: No.the response was like the code I have pasted in the question.so,is there any other mistake I was doing?

Comment: The mistake is that you are serving an improper response and either A) Cannot use JSONP with this backend or B) Need to alter the backend to serve the response in the format I posted. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms for how JSONP works

Comment: but if i do that there is cross origin request problem.thats why i am using jsonp

Comment: @RobM. according to the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): setting the `jsonp` option to `false` prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the `jsonpCallback` setting. For example, `{ jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }`. Thus OP's request is not ill-structured in this regard.

Comment: I think I ahve done the same.please see in the question.